# In cytoscape.js the mouseover event fires only when mouse moves

Tags: cytoscape.js

If the mouse is not moving, the mouseover event does not fire if a node moves under the mouse cursor during animation.

Is there a way to address this, without resorting to a hack like programatically wiggling the mouse?